# Bash conditional statement doesn't work under Cygwin

Tags: bash, makefile, conditional-statements, md5

I have a Makefile rule that generates an MD5 hash for a file, compares it with stored hash from the previous run, and if it is different, updates the stored hash. (I have some files that are generated from a database, so their timestamps are always new and without a MD5 hash I wouldn't know if they really changed or not.) Here it is:

```
CURR=`$(MD5) -q $<`; \
PREV=`if [ -e $@ ] ; then cat $@ ; fi` ; \
if [ "$$CURR" != "$$PREV" ]; then echo $$CURR > $@ ; fi
```

(The `$(MD5)` here is the `md5` tool, which is `md5` on Mac and `md5deep` on Cygwin.)

For some reason this works fine in `bash` under Mac OS X, but doesn't work under Cygwin. I.e. it executes, but the conditional always evaluates to true, so it always updates the hash. I added `echo $$CURR $$PREV` and I see that the hashes look identical, but nonetheless it always updates the hash file.

What am I missing?

Comment: I am a bash novice, but I don't think you should have a semicolon after the if statement. http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html#sect_07_01_02

Comment: not to the point, but why compare MD5s?  if you have both files - just use `diff -q`

Comment: @nhed Oops, I missed your question. The point is that I don't have both files. I see how it could work, although: I could fetch one target from the db and declare it `.PHONY` so it is always fresh, and I could make another target to be a copy of the first, but only update it updated if the first is really different. This is exactly what I do now except that I compare hashes and my second "copy" is a MD5 hash. So it's not much different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo "'$$CURR' '$$PREV'"` and check the whitespace. my guess is that you'll find a difference when using the single quotes (the surrounding double-quotes are necessary for the variables to be interpolated).

if that's the case, one way to fix it is to make sure PREV always contains something, say with `else echo X`, then remove the double-quotes: `if [ $$CURR != $$PREV ];`

Comment: You're absolutely right! Indeed, there was some extra space at the end of `$CURR`. Thank you, now everything works :)